# VBA Macros to compare two columns in two separate excels

Tags: excel, vba

Disclaimer: I am new to VBA and not really a programmer to start with.
I am comparing the values of 2 different columns from 2 excels (old & new version) to see if there are any differences due to changes in background calculations implemented in the new version. I have listed the path to the excel.

I am not sure how do I extract the column from these excels. I will have to match the variables and compare the numbers (since new variables are added to new version) and list out the difference if there are any.

I have to do this for 20 cases so I am thinking of creating a for loop to speed up the code.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Post and image with the columns you are comparing and say what type of comparison you are doing, if necessary show a formula.

Comment: an easy approach is to copy the column in the old file and then choose paste by value into a temporary column in the new Excel file.